# I have 2 requirements. Re-use element id three times AND AND not replicate my code

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278306/jquery-mobile-one-footer-fragment-for-whole-site) [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152446/creating-templated-persistant-header-footer-template-in-jquery-mobile-and-phoneg) at some top StackOverflow responses for how to reuse a header. I cannot get them to work.

1. I have 5 pages
2. I `changePage` between each of them
3. I have hardcoded the same header for all 5 pages, 5 times replication
4. I listen to `document.ajaxStart()` and make a loading animated gif appear
5. I listen to `document.ajaxStop()` and make the animated gif disappear
6. The only way I can get this to work accross all 5 pages is to name the img element to id=loading1, id=loading2, id=loading3,id=loading4,id=loading5
7. If I do not have unique names for the loading images, then only one image works.
8. Obviously,the solution is to RE_USE the header so that the img id=same_ID_for_ALL_5_pages
9. Again, both of the top-rated stack overflow answers are too dense/cryptic for me to understand or reproduce.

> Question(s):

10. Can someone please simplify or explain how I can write proper, elegant code given my simple requirements.
11. And can someone pat me on the back for trying to do simple things with a poorly written library?

Thank you.

Comment: Why write all that text and not provide any code?

Comment: I literally pasted the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278306/jquery-mobile-one-footer-fragment-for-whole-site and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152446/creating-templated-persistant-header-footer-template-in-jquery-mobile-and-phoneg into my app and both failed

Comment: Are your img elements included into every page?

Comment: Yes, and the same header, repeated 5 times have unique ids.  you understand this is wrong, yes?

Comment: There's an excellent jQuery Mobile selector called $.mobile.activePage. Basically this selector is your active page. Because of it you can have 5 pages with identical content and when you use it it will get you only active page content. You can find it here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: it's easier to give the gif image one `.class` instead of 5 unique ids. imagine you have 100 pages, it's hectic to deal with 100 unique ids. Also, you can inject header to each page dynamically without the need to re-write it in each page, here's an example of a `navbar` for 5 pages. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qr97Y/ you can do the same for header or any content.

Comment: @Gajotres submit for answer!

Comment: Done and dona, I hope my comment helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent jQuery Mobile selector called **`$.mobile.activePage`**. Basically this selector is your active page. Because of it you can have 5 pages with identical content and when you use it it will get you only active page content.

More about it can be found [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You understood my question exactly, and you gave a very insightful answer that actually worked!